# Reorganize XML using Java DOM - Hierarchy_Request_Error

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a xml with following scheme structure

```
<test>
    <testcase classname="TestsQuarantine.CreateUsers" name="Administrator"/>
    <testcase classname="TestsQuarantine.Login" name="documentMailQuarantine"/>
    <testcase classname="TestsClerk.CreateUsers" name="John"/>
</test>
```

I need to reorganize it to

```
<test>
    <testsuite name="Quarantine">
        <testcase classname="TestsQuarantine.CreateUsers" name="Administrator"/>
        <testcase classname="TestsQuarantine.Login" name="documentMailQuarantine"/>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Clerk">
        <testcase classname="TestsClerk.CreateUsers" name="John"/>
    </testsuite>
</test>
```

At this point I'm reading the file to NodeList, iterate through it, create new root and try to switch it with original to achieve the structure that I need but I get following error

> HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it
>   is not permitted.

happening in line that performs switch of roots and I'm out of ideas why it is so.. Here is my code:

```
File file = new File(fullPath);
List<Element> clerk = null, 
        quara = null, 
        misc = null;

try {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(file);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("test");
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement(), 
            newRoot = doc.createElement("test");
    clerk = new ArrayList<Element>();
    quara = new ArrayList<Element>();
    misc = new ArrayList<Element>();

    for(int i=0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element node = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        if(node.getAttribute("classname").contains("Clerk")) {
            clerk.add(node);
        } else if(node.getAttribute("classname").contains("Quarantine")) {
            quara.add(node);
        } else {
            misc.add(node);
        }
    }

    if(clerk.isEmpty() == false) {
        Element clerkSuite = doc.createElement("testsuite");
        clerkSuite.setAttribute("name", "Clerk");
        for(Element el : clerk) {
            clerkSuite.appendChild(el);
        }
        newRoot.appendChild(clerkSuite);
    }

    if(quara.isEmpty() == false) {
        Element quaraSuite = doc.createElement("testsuite");
        quaraSuite.setAttribute("name", "Quarantine");
        for(Element el : quara) {
            quaraSuite.appendChild(el);
        }
        newRoot.appendChild(quaraSuite);
    }

    if(misc.isEmpty() == false) {
        Element miscSuite = doc.createElement("testsuite");
        miscSuite.setAttribute("name", "Miscellaneous");
        for(Element el : misc) {
            miscSuite.appendChild(el);
        }
        newRoot.appendChild(miscSuite);
    }

    root.getParentNode().replaceChild(newRoot, root);

    DOMSource original = new DOMSource(doc);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    StreamResult overritten = new StreamResult(fullPath);
    transformer.transform(original, overritten);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What do I have to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iteration over testcase nodes is incorrect. I changed that fragment to below one and Your code is working:

```
Node testNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList testCases= testNode.getChildNodes();

for(int i=0; i < testCases.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = testCases.item(i);

    if (!(n instanceof Text)) {
        Element testCase = (Element) n;

        if (testCase.getAttribute("classname").contains("Clerk")) {
            clerk.add(testCase);
        } else if (testCase.getAttribute("classname").contains("Quarantine")) {
            quara.add(testCase);
        } else {
            misc.add(testCase);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Now I see why I failed, thx!
For those who read taht in the future and may have problem using correct library: you need to import `org.w3c.dom` library so i.e. `org.w3c.dom.Node`